# How to express time?

Tags: time

What should I do in making a sentence consists of time as follows:

The observation is done from 10 AM until 03 PM.

Can I call the 10AM-03PM as midday or day?

Can I rephrase the original sentence as:

The observation is only done during the day, from 10 AM to 03 PM.

Comment: I'm not certain that it's clear what you're asking. Are you asking if we would call the time period from 10am-3 pm "midday"? There's likely no specific term for the time between 10 and 3... 10 am is in the morning and 3 pm is in the afternoon.

Comment: @Catija pls read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I rephrase the original sentence as:
>
> "The observation is only done during the day, from 10 AM to 03 PM."

Numbers aren't generally preceded with 0 when telling time.  But other than that, the sentence is normal.

But you are giving a general range of "done during the day", which usually suggests "during daylight hours".  It's common knowledge that 10 AM to 3 PM is "daytime" (on most of the planet).  So this is redundant, and mentioning "during the day" really just raises questions... such as "why not 4 PM?" and "why not 9 AM?"

So you might just say:

- "The observation takes place from 10 AM to 3 PM."